# Fedora bootup is always failing

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I need modern Linux distribution and Fedora is my first choice but it wont boot on my machine. I have tried Fedora 21 and 22, multiple USB drives, multiple tools for creating install usb (diskpark, suse image creator, rawrite32, rufus), enabling CSM in uefi bios, disabling fast boot but nothing works.. My Fedora always stuck at booting to live UI and media check fails everytime too.. Im downloading image from official mirror and Im always verifying hash.. Any clues? Thank you!

My computer: Haswell CPU, Kingston DDR3 memory, Geforce 9xx series VGA, SSD with Marvel controller (I have tried also SSD with SandForce), ASUS Z97 motherboard and Corsair digital power supply

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: Freeze or boot device not found (in dracut)